# Why do Python emit STORE_SUBSTR when there's already an INPLACE_ADD?

Tags: python, python-internals

If you disassemble the following function

```
def test():
    t = (1, 2, [30])
    t[2] += [40]
    return t
```

You'll see that the corresponding bytecode for `t[2] += [40]` looks like this:

```
  3          18 LOAD_FAST                0 (t)
             21 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             24 DUP_TOPX                 2
             27 BINARY_SUBSCR
             28 LOAD_CONST               4 (40)
             31 BUILD_LIST               1
             34 INPLACE_ADD
             35 ROT_THREE
             36 STORE_SUBSCR
```

`[40]` is concatenated to the list stored in `t[2]` after `INPLACE_ADD`, why does Python decide to add a `STORE_SUBSCR` anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `INPLACE_ADD` only requests that the operation be done in place if possible; if the object is immutable or has not bothered to implement `__iadd__`, `INPLACE_ADD` falls back on regular, not-in-place addition. If the code was

```
t = [1, 2, (30)]
t[2] += (40,)
```

it would obviously be necessary to store the new tuple back into `t[2]`, since the operation produces a new tuple instead of mutating the old one.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `t[2] += [40]` works like this:

```
temp = t[2]
temp += [40] # INPLACE_ADD
t[2] = temp  # STORE_SUBSCR
```

Python actually doesn't update the list in-place, the value is stored in a temporary variable first.

Proof:

```
>>> lst  = [[1], [2], [3]]
>>> def func():
...     lst[0] = [100]
...     return [40]
...
>>> lst[0] += func()
>>> lst
[[1, 40], [2], [3]]  # Not [[100, 40], [2], [3]]
```