# Why does this python code give [3,3]?

Tags: python, list

Consider this code?

```
b = [[5], [3]]
a = b[1]
b[-1] += b.pop()
print(a)
```

This gives `[3,3]`.

You can't explain it by expanding `b[-1] += b.pop()` to `b[-1] = b[-1] + b.pop()` it seems.

Why do you get this output?

Comment: What part specifically are you asking about?

Comment: @Carcigenicate At the end `b=[[3,3]]`. So how does `a = [3,3]` when `a = b[1]`?

Comment: `a` is the list that was at `b[1]` when `a` was initialized. It isn't linked to the second element in `b`.

Comment: Related: [Why do Python emit STORE_SUBSTR when there's already an INPLACE_ADD?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31039969/846892)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because if you work with `b[-1]` the **reference to the second list is only fetched once, next the operation `+=` is done and finally it is stored back into the list**. So `b[-1] += b.pop()` is basically equivalent to:

```
tmp = b[-1]  # tmp = [3]
tmp += b.pop() # tmp = [3,3], b = [[5]]
b[-1] = tmp # tmp = [3,3], b = [[3,3]]
```

(but of course there is `tmp`, the above fragment is done at interpreter level)

Now `tmp` is a **refence** to the second list in `b` (so `tmp is a`). So this means that you extend *inplace* `a` with `b.pop()`. `b.pop()` is `[3]`. So what you do is you extend `tmp` (which is `[3]` at that moment) with `tmp`. And so `tmp` (and thus `a` becomes `[3,3]`). So `b` is now `[[3,3]]`.

Mind that **`x += y` for `list`s is not equivalent to `x = x+y`**. Indeed, if you write code like:

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> b = a
>>> b = b + [2]
>>> print(a,b)
[1] [1, 2]
```

this will **not update `a`** (since it is not done *inplace*). Whereas for:

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> b = a
>>> b += [2]
>>> print(a,b)
[1, 2] [1, 2]
```

will result in `a` and `b` being both `[1,2]`. Of course, usually `+=` is supposed to behave like adding, but the adding is done *inplace* which can have some effects.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing b[-1] right before you print a. b[-1] refers to the last element in b, which you are adding another element to. It appears that this happens because when you do `a = b[1]`, it must be assigned by reference since a is updated when b[1] (same as b[-1] in this case) is updated.

Answer (score 0):

First there are only 2 elements in the list b.

```
b = [[5], [3]]
a = b[1]

print b[1] 
# gives [3]
print b[-1] 
# also gives [3] because here -1 refers to the last element and there are 
# only two elements.

b[-1] += b.pop()
# here you are appending 3 to [3] of b

print b[-1] 
print a
# that is why when you print a it gives [3,3] as the b[1] value was 
# appended to a in the second step itself and you are just printing here.
```

Hope you got what I am trying to say..